# $F$-Automorphism of $F(w)$ induces automorphism on $\{1,w,w^2,...,w^{n-1} \}$ only if $w$ primitive n-th root?

Tags: galois-theory

I just stumble across a theorem in Galois theory, that says that if F is a field of characteristic p and $w$ is a primitive n-th root of unity with $p \nmid n$ than if we take a $F$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $F(w)$, then $\sigma$ induces an automorphism $\sigma_0$ of $\{1,w,w^2,...,w^{n-1}\}$ by restricting $\sigma$ to this set. But I was wondering : What could go wrong if $w$ was just an algebraic element over $F$ and not a primitive root of unity?

Comment: The point is that $\{1,w,w^2,\ldots, w^{n-1}\}$ is a group under multiplication. This clearly is not the case when $w$ is just algebraic.

Comment: @freakish: Surely the powers of any element of $F(w)$ form a group under multiplication irrespective of whether $w$ is a root of unity or not. I think this is more about the group of units of order dividing $n$ being *unique*, and hence *fixed by $\sigma$* (as a set).

Comment: So what could wrong is that unless $w$ has finite order it may happen that $\sigma(w)$ is not a power of $w$ at all. For example, let $F=\Bbb{F}_2(x)$ be a field of rational functions, $x$ transcental over the prime field. Assume that $w$ satisfies the equation $w^2+w=x$. Then $w$ is algebraic over $F$ and the only non-trivial automorphism of $F(w)/F$ is determined by $\sigma(w)=w+1$. We cannot have $w+1=w^k$ for any $k\in\Bbb{Z}$ for then $w$ would be algebraic over the prime field.

Comment: Thanks, but why the only non-trivial F-automorphism is $\sigma(w)=w+1$? Shouldn't it send $w$ to a root of the minimal polynomial $y^2+y-x$?

Comment: The roots of $y^2+y-x$ are $w$ and $w+1$. Characteristic two is essential.